# RequireJS module for SignalR

Tags: requirejs, signalr

Rather than copy and pasting my code onto here, I have uploaded it to [github](https://github.com/mhooper/SignalRReady/blob/master/SignalRReady.js).  The RequireJS module does have a dependency on jquery.signalr and in tern has a dependency on jquery but also have a dependency on the javascript held in /signalr/hubs.  There is a bit of config to do with `Require.Config`.

Basically what is happening is on the first time you load the page the connection is made to the hubs within signalr and the "server side" code is executed and does the desired thing.  When you refresh the page it does not.  All client side code is called, so for example:

```
var myViewModel = new MyViewMode();
myViewModel.init();
```

and within your init method you have

```
var connection = $.connection.myHub;
this.init = function() {
  connection.server.myMethod();
}
```

this would then go off to

```
public MyHub : Hub 
{
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        Client.Request.populateSomeInformation() // I think it's request but I'm doing this from memory!
    }
}
```

and then call

```
connection.client.populateSomeInformation = function () { .. )
```

but doesn't call this :(

It *looks* like a connection has been made (using the good old `console.log()` to see what it outputs) and indeed debugging the project it executes the code within the hub but there is no response made back to the javascript.

So wonderful people of the internet, where am I going wrong?  Do I need to check the state of `$.connection.hub.start();` before attempting to start it again?

Time for beer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it should be

```
connection.client.populateSomeInformation = function () { .. )
```

(not connection.server)

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#callclient

---

*(observations on the code you have on github right now)*

```js
var isLoaded = false;

// ... some code that doesn't change isLoaded ...

if (isLoaded == false) {       
    scrollIntervalId = window.setInterval(function () {
        signalRLoaded();
    }, 30);

}
```

I think `isLoaded` will always be false at this point. Not sure what you intended this to accomplish.

```js
var connection = $.connection.hub.start();
```

I don't think you're supposed to open the connection before defining any client functions. I don't see any client functions being defined here, so maybe you're doing that somewhere else? I don't know if it really matters other than if the server attempts to call a client function that hasn't yet been defined...

```js
function SignalRReady(callback) {
    if (isLoaded) {
        callback(connection);
    } else {
        readyCalls = callback;
    }

    return SignalRReady;
}

SignalRReady.version = "1.0.0";

SignalRReady.load = function(name, request, onLoad, config) {
    if (config.isBuild) {
        onLoad();
    } else {
        SignalRReady(onLoad);
    }
};

return SignalRReady;
```

I'm confused by this bit of code, probably because I don't see how it's being used. Is this an attempt at a kind of singleton? I see that SignalRReady is the "class" being returned for the module. You're not really returning an object, you're returning a constructor which implies that you're instantiating it in other places, something like

```js
define(['SignalRReady'], function(sigR)
{
    var srr = new sigR();
});
```

But then you have that `load` function defined that calls the constructor and makes this look all weird. How are you using this?

Anyways, I'm thinking you might be hitting some kind of race condition where the client function may not always be available at the time the server is trying to call it.

---

(additional comments/code 2013-09-06)

Your connection object is actually a jQuery promise ( http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/ ).

If you're unfamiliar with promises, think of them generically as a queue of callbacks to be executed later. In this case, when connected, all the callbacks will be executed (in the order they were added). If a callback is added after being connected, it will get executed immediately. This is how your code is working now. You add the callback to the .done queue after the connection is made and is executed immediately.

If you insist on creating the connection object yourself, then you do not need to use the stateChanged event. You just add the callback to the .done queue:

```js
define(function()
{
    function signalRReady(callback)
    {
        if (window.connection == undefined) {
            window.connection = $.connection.hub.start();
        }

        window.connection.done(callback);
    }

    signalRReady.version = "1.0.0";
    return signalRReady;
});
```

However, I believe it's not a good idea to initiate the connection yourself. Because your module isn't a complete wrapper around SignalR such that people would only use your module to do SignalR stuff, you are not guaranteed (and cannot expect) other code will not initiate the connection. Especially if someone is adding your module to an existing codebase.

Your module is simply adding a new event, so keep it simple. Take the callback and execute it yourself when appropriate:

```js
define(function()
{
    function signalRReady(callback)
    {
        $.connection.hub.stateChanged(function (state)
        {
            if(state.newState === $.signalR.connectionState.connected)
            {
                callback();
            }
        });
    }

    signalRReady.version = "1.0.0";
    return signalRReady;
});
```

Nowadays, promises are pretty popular. You might want to implement a promise-based module like:

```js
define(function()
{
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    $.connection.hub.stateChanged(function (state)
    {
        if(state.newState === $.signalR.connectionState.connected)
        {
            // executes all callbacks attached by the "ready" function below
            deferred.resolve();
        }
    });

    return {
        ready: function(callback)
        {
            deferred.done(callback);
        },

        version: "1.0.0"
    };
});
```

If callbacks are attached after the connection has been made, they are executed immediately.

Also, notice this example module's init function returns an object instead of a function. Since RequireJS will pass the same instance around to any module that requires it, state is maintained - we can use local variables instead of global.

Comment: It was - just realised that I typed it out incorrectly when I posted this.

Comment: Ok, well, the code you linked to has some logic issues.Also, there's nothing that shows how you're using the module. It seems like you're saying your problem is when you first go the page it works but when you refresh the page it doesn't. But you're not showing everything that's running. I'll update my "answer" with some observations on the code you have in github right now and see if anything sparks an idea.

Comment: I have made a number of changes (basically tried not to retro-fit the domReady plugin) and gone back to basics. As you have commented on this, I would be interested to read your thoughts on this.

Comment: Much better - cleaner, easier to follow, easier to understand. However, I think you should try a different approach. Being a module that only detects when connected and raise a **Ready event, I don't think it should be one to initiate the connection. Check out http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#connectionlifetime (specifically, the stateChanged event). No polling necessary - you're told when connected.

Comment: Works a treat - stateChanged has reduced the amount of code needed.  I have had to use window.connection as the connection needs to be available globally for when this module is called upon again.  Thanks again - your comments really helped me achieve what I wanted!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm going to edit this answer with more comments and code (that can't be done in a comment)